# Is there a way to detect when scroll begins and ends in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm looking for the equivalent of ListView's LVN_BEGINSCROLL and LVN_ENDSCROLL, but in a TreeView. I'm currently using C# / winforms but would be happy with a C++ or WPF solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a custom implementation in the following MSDN thread: [**Treeview Scrollbar Event (detecting/controlling)**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3ea9a4d3-0614-4d4f-a861-3cb30ca1bda0)